# Two Data Entries After Converting BTRFS Profile

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, profile

I ran the following command on a BTRFS volume in order to convert the data profile from single to DUP (I'm looking to provide duplicate data on this volume to be able to repair possible bit rot corruption):

`sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=dup Volume`

However, now when I run `btrfs filesystem df Volume` I get two Data entries, one with the original single profile and one with the new DUP profile:

```
Data, DUP: total=1.00GiB, used=8.00KiB
Data, single: total=1.00GiB, used=0.00B
System, DUP: total=8.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, DUP: total=256.00MiB, used=208.00KiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=16.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

I'm assuming that that is not correct. What should I have done differently? Is there a more correct way to convert from single to DUP profile?

Comment: if this was sustained after a reboot and writing some data on it I'd writeup reproduction and post the mailinglist or report a bug